# Getting 500 error into frisby delete request

Tags: jasmine, frisby.js

Hello I am facing 500 error during delete request into frisby. The code is below please correct me if I have done any wrong..!

```
var frisby = require('frisby');

//get the current UTC time from this URL: (https://currentmillis.com/)
var now = new Date();
var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds())
var currentUTCTime = now_utc.getTime() - (now_utc.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

frisby.create('Authentication for Delete Request Valid User Name and Password')  
     .delete('http://example.com',
      {
       headers:
        {
              'Accept':'application/json',
              'Auth-Username':'abcd',
              'X-Application-Key':'xyzzzz',
              'Content-Type':'application/json',
              'x-locale':'en_US',
              'x-microtime':currentUTCTime, //get the current UTC time
              'auth-signature': 'example', // Added new auth-signature for new responses
              }
           }   
        )
    .expectStatus(200)
    .toss()
```

Answer (score 0):

500 signifies internal server error. Which means your REST call broke something in the server. Please check server logs to see the real issue. There might be some problem server side for this.